# Adjust multiple Taskwarrior task due dates by a specific amount

Tags: taskwarrior

I like to create Tasks corresponding to chapters in books. In this way, I can create a schedule for reading which allows me to know when I'll finish a book, where I'll be by such-and-such date, ETC. Given that I like to read several books at a time, scheduling chapters like this helps me stay organized and not focus too much on one book over the others.

So far I've been scheduling chapters as individual tasks, with the title of the book being the task's project.

The issue I have is that occasionally, I will end up getting behind one week on a book. I'm OK with this so long as it's occasional, and I'd like to be able to "shift" all the due dates for this book (project) by one week. I can accomplish this manually, task by task. But is there anyway to say something like "for all tasks in project:xyz, add 1 week to due date"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's possible:

```
task +PENDING pro:xyz mod due:due+1week
```

I added the `+PENDING` filter to the command since I assume you don't want to modify all tasks of the project, but just those you haven't finished yet.

Comment: Spot on. Good catch on the virtual tag as well.